# React UserContext: Conditional in useEffect is being ignored

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I am using the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook to make a component which shares state to other components.

Right now this component is saving the state to local storage as well.

```
var initialState = {
  avatar: '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg',
  isRoutingVisible: false,
  removeRoutingMachine: false,
  markers: [],
  currentMap: {}
};

var UserContext = React.createContext();

function setLocalStorage(key, value) {
  function isJson(item) {
    item = typeof item !== 'string' ? JSON.stringify(item) : item;

    try {
      item = JSON.parse(item);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }

    if (typeof item === 'object' && item !== null) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  try {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (errors) {
    // catch possible errors:
    console.log(errors);
  }
}

function getLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  try {
    const value = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    return value ? JSON.parse(value) : initialValue;
  } catch (e) {
    return initialValue;
  }
}

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => getLocalStorage('user', initialState));
```

Right after I am declaring some useEffect hooks:

```
const [
    isLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo,
    setIsLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo
  ] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage('user', user);
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('user.isRoutingVisibile ', user.isRoutingVisibile);
  }, [user.isRoutingVisibile]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('user.markers.length ', user.markers.length);
    if (user.markers.length === 2) {
      setIsLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo(false);
    }

    return () => {};
  }, [JSON.stringify(user.markers)]

);
```

The last hook is the head scratcher, I am passing an array in the dependency, which I'd like to react (ha!) to do something when the array length gets to two.

When it does get there, I have a useState hook which will change the value of a variable.

```
 const [
    isLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo,
    setIsLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo
  ] = useState(true);
```

I have a function which I'd like to pass to another component which should only be able to fire when the ternary return true.

Right now despite the Array's length getting to two, the `setIsLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo` doesn't change the variable to `false`

```
return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
     
        setUserMarkers: marker => {
          console.log('marker ', marker);

          console.log(
            'isLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo ',
            isLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo
          );
          isLengthOfUserMarkersLessThanTwo === true
            ? setUser(user => ({
                ...user,
                markers: [...user.markers, marker]
              }))
            : () => null;
        },
        
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you combine this in one codesandbox for example?

Comment: also there is no need to for returning noop function in the last useEffect

Comment: @AmirhosseinEbrahimi This app uses various API's so they won't work, LMK if this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-shape-sfcoo?file=/components/Context/UserContext.jsx) works.

Comment: it doesn't run due to its size, but I see your source code, and useReducer is what you need, you can take a look at this greater [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively/). If you want I can write an answer about how to convert it with useReducer

Comment: Oh thank you for sharing the article! Yeah, could you, if you wouldn't mind? I guess I have been spending too much time on it! THANK YOU!

Comment: I actually figured it out my friend! `Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime!` Happy new year!

Comment: Thank you, @Antonio Pavicevac-Ortiz, wish you a great year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing function as a state may not be what you want, also passing the function to update a slice of reacting state, is simply solved by a great stage manager such as redux. for simple projects, redux may be overkill, react itself can handle these scenarios by Context behind the scene. It will also become more readable with react Hooks. here is a simple demonstration of how to use React hooks to make it more predictable.

```
const UserStateContext = React.createContext()
const UserDispatchContext = React.createContext()

function userReducer(state, {type, payload}){
  switch (type) {
    case 'setId': {
      return {...state, id: payload.id}
    }
    case 'setAvatar': {
      return {...state, avatar: payload.avatar}
    }
    // ...
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${type}`)
    }
  }
}

const initialState = {
  avatar: '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg',
  isRoutingVisible: false,
  // ...
};


function UserProvider({children}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(userReducer, initialState)
  return (
    <UserStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <UserDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </UserDispatchContext.Provider>
    </UserStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

function useUserState() {
  return React.useContext(UserStateContext)
}

function useUserDispatch() {
  return React.useContext(CountDispatchContext)
}

function useUser() {
  return [useUserState(), useUserDispatch()]
}
```

Now you can use this in children component like the following:

```
const AvatarChildren = () => {
  const [user, dispatch] = useUser()

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={user.avatar} />
      <button 
        onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'setAvatar', 
                                  payload: {avatar: 'newAvatarSrc'} })}
      >
       Change Avatar
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can even make it simpler such as

```
const userReducer = (state, action) => ({state, ...action})
```

and use it like this

```
onClick={() => dispatch({avatar: 'newAvatarSrc'})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amirhossein Ebrahimi! He pointed me to a [great article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively/) by Kent C. Dodds!

I added this code based on it.

I just added the reducer but one should really check out the article as he adds some error checking for the Context (something I should do).

Just added this reducer:

```
  function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwoFalse': {
        return {
          isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: (state.isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo = false)
        };
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
      }
    }
  }
```

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: true });

Then later in my useEffect hook:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (user.markers.length === 2) {
      dispatch({ type: 'isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwoFalse' });
    }
  }, [JSON.stringify(user.markers)]);
```

And then return it in the Provider so it can be consumed by its children:

```
return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        setUserMarkers: marker => {

          state.isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo // using the var to control the ternary depending on useEffect!

            ? setUser(user => ({
                ...user,
                markers: [...user.markers, marker]
              }))
            : () => null;
        }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
```

Thanks again Amirhossein!