# Within a parent component, is there any way I can access a prop from a child component?

Tags: reactjs

There's a problem I frequently run into when building React projects - I'll need a prop in component, but can't access it because it violates the unidirectional flow of props.

Here's the specific problem I have now:
In my `CafeReviews.jsx` component, I need to access a piece of data `averageRating` - however, this property is contained with the child component `Review.jsx`. 
So I need to access this data within `CafeReviews`, so that I can pass it as a prop to `<CafeHeader/>`.

Any ideas on how I can solve this, without having to restructure my components?

This is the parent component `CafeReviews.jsx`

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Review from './Review'
import CafeHeader from './CafeHeader'

const CafeReviews = ({ match }) => {
  const [cafe, setCafe] = useState([]);
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/cafe/${match.params.id}`).then((result) => {
      setCafe(result.data);
    })
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/all-reviews")
      .then((review) => {
        setReviews(review.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }, [])

  let filteredReviews = reviews.filter((review) => {
    return review.cafeName === cafe.cafeName;
  });


  return (
    <div>
      <CafeHeader cafe={cafe} />
      <div className="reviews-container">
      <Review reviews={filteredReviews} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CafeReviews
```

...and one of the child components, `Review.jsx`, containing the `averageRating` property I want to access:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {convertToStars, averageStarRating} from '../helperFunctions'

const Review = (props) => {
  const { reviews } = props;

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    axios
      .delete(`/api/reviews/${id}`)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("review successfully deleted");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
      reviews.map((review) => {
        const { title, userName, blurb, stars, _id } = review;

        const starRating = convertToStars(stars)
        const averageRating = averageStarRating(reviews)

        return (
          <div  className = 'review-container'>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            {starRating.map((item) => {
              return item
            })}
            <h2>{`Review by: ${userName}`}</h2>
            <p>{blurb}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleClick(_id)}>Delete</button>
          </div>
        )
      })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Review
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65731935/12082336

Answer (score 1):

Set up a piece of state in your parent element CafeReviews and pass down a function as a prop to change that state.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Review from './Review'
import CafeHeader from './CafeHeader'

const CafeReviews = ({ match }) => {
  const [cafe, setCafe] = useState([]);
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
  // change here
  const [infoFromChild, setInfo] = useState(null);
  const getDataFromChild = useCallback(data => setInfo(data),[]);
//
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/cafe/${match.params.id}`).then((result) => {
      setCafe(result.data);
    })
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/all-reviews")
      .then((review) => {
        setReviews(review.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }, [])

  let filteredReviews = reviews.filter((review) => {
    return review.cafeName === cafe.cafeName;
  });


  return (
    <div>
      <CafeHeader cafe={cafe} getDataFromChild={getDataFromChild}/>
      <div className="reviews-container">
      <Review reviews={filteredReviews} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {convertToStars, averageStarRating} from '../helperFunctions'

const Review = (props) => {
  const { reviews, getDataFromChild } = props;

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    axios
      .delete(`/api/reviews/${id}`)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("review successfully deleted");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
      reviews.map((review) => {
        const { title, userName, blurb, stars, _id } = review;

        const starRating = convertToStars(stars)
        const averageRating = averageStarRating(reviews)
        //added here
        getDataFromChild(averageRating);
        return (
          <div  className = 'review-container'>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            {starRating.map((item) => {
              return item
            })}
            <h2>{`Review by: ${userName}`}</h2>
            <p>{blurb}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleClick(_id)}>Delete</button>
          </div>
        )
      })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Review
```

Answer (score 0):

React designed with unidirectional flow in mind, so it's better to hoist your fetch to a higher level and pass functions and data to the child component as props.

but there are some ways to access the child component data in the parent component.

1. State management
   Redux for example can be used to centralizing your application's state. so the state is accessible in nearly all components.
2. React Context API

> but for the small app, it may be overkill to use redux configuration, there are some simpler things e.g. immer-store but it may harm you in little duo to support and community issue. The React way itself provides a method for these scenarios called `context`. Here is a great [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively/) about how to use react context effectively for a simple project

3. React useImperativeHandle

```
const Child = (props, ref) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState)

  useEffect(() => { /*save fetched items in state */}, [])

  const getHandlerFunctions = () => ({
    getState: () => state,
    otherCallbacks: () => otherFallback(state, ...args)
  })

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, getHandlerFunctions, [dependencies])

  return <div data-type="your-child-component" />
}

export default  React.forwardRef(Child);
```

and then grab your data in the parent component like this

```
const Parent = () => {
 const childRef = React.useRef()

  const callback = () => {
    const { current: child } = childRef
    if (!child) return
    child.getState() // will return updated state
    child.otherCallbacks() 

  }
}
```

4. js let
   This may help you use this function even outside the react component

```
let _callback = () => {}

const Child = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState)

  // you can change dependensis by your need
  React.useEffect(() => {
    _callback = (...args) => {
      console.log('do anything with', state, ...args)
    }

    return () => {
      _callback = () => {}
    }
  })

}

export const struct = {
  get callback() {
    return _callback
  },
}
```

You can read more about these solution in [Use callback definition of a functional component outside the component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65608430/10321531)
 and [React UserContext: Conditional in useEffect is being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570366/10321531)